# Print Scale by CSS

Tags: css, printing

On IE 8 and Firefox (3.6 and 4), if you go to Print Preview, you adjust the Print Scale by a a percentage or use Shrink to Fit. Does CSS have a property like scale:50%; or something to adjust the print scale?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is Zoom:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/zoom

And moz/webkit-transform:

http://help.dottoro.com/lcebdggm.php

Comment: oddly enough, zoom works differently on IE 8. in IE 7 it works the way I want it to: makes everything inside the body larger or smaller. in IE 8 it expands or contracts the body itself by whatever percentage you pick. I'm not sure which implementation is the bug.

Comment: Heads up that CSS combined with printing has always been buggy in most versions of IE.

Comment: sitepoint.com link is dead.  But this is what worked for me: @media print {
    html {zoom: 75%;} }

Comment: @DA. If you are still around, can you write out what the link said?  I'm interested in this answer.

Comment: @Thomas are you asking me if I remember what a page I looked at 10 years ago had said? :)  Alas, my brain is 10 years older and not what it used to be. But, I assume it was referencing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom but as that page notes, it never really became a standard.

Comment: @DA.  :) Same here, at my age, I struggle with remembering or refinding random pages I found a few weeks ago.  On the other hand, if you continue using custom print settings, you might have an update that could benefit others.  I have offline browser tools that I use with my company that would really look much nicer if I could override browser defaults and when people create new questions the administrators foolishly shut them down as already answered because a 10 year old link that was once a useful solution.

Comment: For me, ZOOM only was working for printing when set on the HTML tag.

Comment: @cskwg It doesn't seem to work for me neither with the body tag, nor with the html tag on Chrome 109.0.5414.74. Any ideas if there is a new solution for scaling the webpage on print?

Answer (score 6):

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">

body {
  zoom:75%; /*or whatever percentage you need, play around with this number*/
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since zoom or -ms-zoom doesn't work the way I expected it to on IE8, I ended up fiddling with the font-size and tr sizes. Hopefully MS makes a zoom that works like the Print Scale/Size functionality in the Print window from the browser.